# VtigerCRM task scheduling module

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api, crm, vtiger

I have a company for bike servicing and have 20 workers. 
Now I want to schedule new job ( new bike service ) to free worker.

See below scenario which I want to manage.

1. Each worker can only work 9am-9pm Monday to Friday.
2. But we will also need to check the worker's calendar to see if they have any job already.
3. Once we will check and get free worker then able to assign job to that worker.

Can anyone  please suggest any solution how to manage it in vtigerCRM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a job module. Configure all required fields for that module.
2. Create a custom-view to get the list of all workers who are not having any job for a specific hour.
3. Create a new job and then assign this job to that worker.

Comment: Yes I am agree with you but is there any way to achieve it directly like by installing any modules.